# function code from the book "Natural Language Processing with Transformers"

Tags: python, syntax

I have never seen this repeated dot syntax, and I can't find any pointers to it anywhere.

Is it application of unsqueeze followed by expand followed by float() ?

```
input_mask_expanded = (attention_mask 

                           .unsqueeze(-1)

                           .expand(token_embeddings.size())

                           .float())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to

```
input_mask_expanded = (attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float())
```

Just in a more readable form